# title_permalink of related entry => firefox Content Encoding Error

Tags: ee2, relationships

I have a problem with Firefox (Mac version 21.0), Expression Engine (Core, version 2.6.1) Relationships, and getting the title_permalink of the related entry.

I have a channel 'Teasers' with a field teaser_event which is a relationship (single) to channels 'Other Event' and 'Random Event'.

The template (trimmed, but still exhibiting the bug) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  {exp:channel:entries channel="teaser"}
    {teaser_event:title_permalink='site/event'}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get in firefox is 'Content Encoding Error - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.'

It works fine in Safari and Chrome.

If I remove the *='site/event'* from the title_permalink tag, then it works in firefox as well.

This is running locally. Version info:

```
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 12 2012 15:09:37
$ php --version
PHP 5.3.15 (cli) (built: Jul 31 2012 18:42:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.10, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: Looks like you template have an issue that is messing up the encoding. Please, improve the sample code in the channel:entries tags.